# Chat on node.js

Tags: node.js, shell, tcp, chat, tcpclient

Require the modules

```
var net = require("net");
```

Store the users and the connections number
    var count = 0,
        users = {};

Creates the server

```
var server = net.createServer(function (conn){
```

Stores the current nickname and set the utf8 encoding

```
var nickname;
conn.setEncoding('utf8');
```

Shows a message on the shell when you stablish a connection

```
conn.write(' > welcome to \033[92mnode-chat\033[39m!'
    + '\n > ' + count + ' other people are connected at this time.'
    + '\n > please write your name and press enter: ');
```

The number of connections++

```
count++;
```

When recives data it checks if there is a user in the storage with that name shows a message and return. Else shows a welcome message. Otherwise, if you input a message or any data (after have registered your nickname) shows it on the shell.

```
conn.on('data', function (data){
    data = data.replace('\r\n', '');
    if(!nickname) {
        if(users[data]) {
            conn.write('\033[93m > nickname already in use. Try again:\033[39m ');
            return;
        } else {
            nickname = data;
            users[nickname] = conn;

            for(var i in users) {
                users[i].write('\033[90m > ' + nickname + ' joined the room\033[39m\n');
            }
        }
    } else {
        for(var i in users) {
            if(i != nickname) {
                users[i].write('\033[96m > ' + nickname + ':\033[39m ' + data + '\n');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

When you close or end the connection deletes your nickname from the storage, number of connections-- and shows a message.

```
conn.on('close', function(){
    count--;
    delete users[nickname];
    conn.write('\033[90 > ' + nickname + ' left the room\033[39m\n');
});
});
```

Server on port 3000

```
server.listen(3000, function (){
    console.log('\033[96m   server listening on *:3000\033[39m');
});
```

I have a bug in my chat. I stablish two telnet connections using de shell. But when I close one the other one close two, and shows me a error message. What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to `write` to a closed connection, which will fail since writing to a closed `Writable` stream throws an error.

```
conn.on('close', function(){
    count--;
    delete users[nickname];
    conn.write('\033[90 > ' + nickname + ' left the room\033[39m\n');
});
```

What you want is to broadcast the message to all other users either using `Object.keys` or a `for-in` loop.

```
conn.on('close', function() {
  count --;
  delete users[nickname];
  Object.keys(users).forEach(function (user) {
    users[user].write(nickname + ' left the room');
  });
}
```

You also don't need a separate `count` variable to track connected users.

```
Object.keys(users).length;
```

> But when I close one the other one close two, and shows me a error
>   message

It is because you're not listening for an `error` event and, by default, an `EventEmitter` **throws** an error if an error occurs and no error listener is attached.

```
conn.on('error', console.log);
```

Comment: When I add that code and I close the connection appears this:
Connection closed by foreign host.
events.js:82
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: This socket has been ended by the other party
    at Socket.writeAfterFIN [as write] (net.js:265:12)
    at /home/michel/Escritorio/ejemplos-nodejs/chat/index.js:45:9
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/michel/Escritorio/ejemplos-nodejs/chat/index.js:44:25)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:104:17)
    at TCP.close (net.js:458:12)

Comment: Yes, please refer to the last part of my post. You need to attach an `error` handler for `conn`